# What is the best way and how to store and upload articles for a newspaper using php, mysql, and/or javascript

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am currently working on making a website for the newspaper of my school and seek advice on how to store and upload efficiently articles. I've tried my best using php and mysql to retrieve data such as title, topic, image, etc from a database called article and then return it as html 
to later echo it. I wondered first what was the best way to do it and if a database is really necessary. And second, could you please help me fix this code for when I run it on localhost, it doesn't print anything. Here's the code:

```
    <?php
          $dbc = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "password", "newspaper")
          or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
          $edition_date = '2018-04-01';
          function app(){
              global $dbc;
              global $edition_date;
              $scope = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT id FROM article WHERE dateofpublication = $edition_date ");
              $row_login = mysqli_num_rows($scope);
              if ($row_login != '') {
                $return = "";
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $row_login; $i++) {
                    $j = $i - 1;
                    $id = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT id FROM article WHERE dateofpublication = '$edition_date' ORDER BY order LIMIT 1 OFFSET $j ");
                    $title = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT title FROM article WHERE dateofpublication = '$edition_date' ORDER BY order LIMIT 1 OFFSET $j ");
                    $topic = array(unserialize(mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT topic FROM article WHERE dateofpublication = '$edition_date' ORDER BY order LIMIT 1 OFFSET $j ")));
                    $summary = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT summary FROM article WHERE dateofpublication = '$edition_date' ORDER BY order LIMIT 1 OFFSET $j ");
                    $article = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT article FROM article WHERE dateofpublication = '$edition_date' ORDER BY order LIMIT 1 OFFSET $j ");
                    $idauthor = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT idauthor FROM article WHERE dateofpublication = '$edition_date' ORDER BY order LIMIT 1 OFFSET $j ");
                    $author = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT title FROM user WHERE id = $idauthor ");
                    $image = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT image FROM article WHERE dateofpublication = '$edition_date' ORDER BY order LIMIT 1 OFFSET $j ");
                    $imagedesc = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT imagedescription FROM article WHERE dateofpublication = '$edition_date' ORDER BY order LIMIT 1 OFFSET $j ");
                    $moment = "<div class=\"article-box box-length-".$boxlength." box-type-".$boxtype."\"><a href=\"node/article.php?value=".$id."\"><img class=\"central-image\" src=\"modif/img/articles/".$image."\" /></a>
                        <span class=\"img-description\">".$imagedesc."</span>
                        <a href=\"node/article.php?value=".$id."\"><span class=\"title\">".$title."</span></a>
                        <span class=\"summary\">".$summary."</span>
                        <div class=\"add-ons\">
                          <span class=\"author\">by ".$author."</span><span class=\"seperative\"></span>
                          <span class=\"dateofpublication\">".$edition_date."</span>
                          <div class=\"voters\">
                            <img class=\"like-button\" src=\"modif/img/tools/likebutton.png\"/><span class=\"number-likes\"><span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>";
                    $return .= $moment;
                };
                return $return;
              };
            };
          ?>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
    document.getElementsByTagName('body').innerHTML =
<?php echo app(); ?>;
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I thank you in advance.

Comment: Wow. That's something that needs too much of fixing. I bet your server must have died by now.

Comment: 1. You can select more than one column in the same query. So start by amending all those queries to do something like `SELECT id,title,topic,...... FROM...`

Comment: As to the rest, I am afraid there are just to many issues, and SO is not a tutorial site

Comment: Oh and YES a database is going to be very necessary

Comment: Thank you very much. I have to say that I have to say that I lack experience on backend. Anyways, isn't it better to use ajax for this job?

Comment: Wow. This is the most chaotic attempt at extracting something from MySQL I have ever seen. I think you may need to read up on some basic SQL before you go any further.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.

```
 SELECT * FROM articles
      WHERE dateofpublication = '$edition_date'
      ORDER BY order
```

Will give you an ordered array of (ordered or associative) arrays.  Then us PHP to walk through that.

Do not grab each column one at a time.

Do not grab only one row at a time.

Do not use `OFFSET`; if rows are being inserted/deleted while this is being performed, you could get mysterious duplicate/skipped records.